# VueJs auth not passing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having some problems with authentication with Vue.
I'm trying to check user data and return him if he is validated or not, I'm catching errors as well, but this is meant in case if some other error happens.
This is my code:

```
loginJWT ({ commit }, payload) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      jwt.login(payload.userDetails.email, payload.userDetails.password)
        .then(response => {

          // If there's user data in response
          if (response.data.userData) {
            // Navigate User to homepage
            router.push(router.currentRoute.query.to || '/')

            // Set accessToken
            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.data.accessToken)

            // Update user details
            commit('UPDATE_USER_INFO', response.data.userData, {root: true})

            // Set bearer token in axios
            commit('SET_BEARER', response.data.accessToken)

            resolve(response)
            console.log(response.data.accessToken);

          } else {
            reject({message: 'Wrong Email or Password'})
          }

        })
        .catch(error => { reject(error) })
    })
  }
```

As you see I have 'Wrong Email or Passoword', but this message never showed.
I tried like `if(response.status === 200)` and `else if(response.status === 400)` to catch that status and show the message, but no success anyway. Ofc when I put invalid credentials, it's returning 'Request failed with status code 400', but I want to show 'Wrong Email Or password'.
I even tried to check if first gives response status 400 before even check if there is response.data.userData like:

```
if(response.status == 400){
            reject({message: 'Wrong Email or Password'})
  }
```

But still not a success.

What I really want to return is the message that I'm giving from the response, I could just return the message 'something is wrong' in .catch(error), but I can't catch response.data.message like this, because I have message receiving from my backend.
Any ideas on how to resolve it?

Comment: is there a reason you use `new Promise` here? i dont see one

Comment: I think you should check the "error" object inside the catch block. Usually, the API throws a 400 or 401 exception and it should be caught inside the "catch" block of the promise, not inside the "then" block.